# Как получить данные из http запроса в Java

Tags: java

Сервис по этому URL

```
http://www.free-kassa.ru/api.php?merchant_id=136624&s=a44405c624c12047dd9d4e7dc5d08a24&action=get_balance
```

Возвращает такой XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <answer>info</answer>
    <desc>Merchant balance</desc>
    <balance>0.00</balance>
</root>
```

Мне нужно из него вытащить значение 0. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать с помощью http запроса в Java?

```
String url = "http://www.free-kassa.ru/api.php";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

Мучаюсь уже пару часов, не могу найти ответ.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо, я теперь хоть понял в какую сторону копать!

Comment: @StrangerintheQ
Если не затруднит, не могли бы Вы мне объяснить такой момент. Дело в том, что во всех туториалах xml-файл лежит локально. А я пытаюсь сделать запрос на веб-страницу.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ
Я имею ввиду, что xml во всех примерах берется локально и для него создается переменная типа File, где в дальнейшем указывается путь, где лежит xml-файл.

В моем же случае, xml-файл лежит по адресу: http://www.free-kassa.ru/api.php?merchant_id=136624&s=a44405c624c12047dd9d4e7dc5d08a24&action=get_balance

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder#parse(java.io.InputStream)` передав ему на вход `ByteArrayInputStream`, созданный от строки с Вашими данными

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://www.free-kassa.ru/api.php?merchant_id=136624&s=a44405c624c12047dd9d4e7dc5d08a24&action=get_balance";
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.toString().getBytes()));

        String balance = doc.getDocumentElement()
                .getElementsByTagName("balance").item(0).getTextContent();

        System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
    }
}
```

> ```
> balance = 0.00
> ```

Comment: Конечно! 
Но у меня почему то вылетает исключение:

`Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL`

Comment: Я через IntellijIdea запускаю. Все-равно исключение

Comment: @АртемСавельев для запроса я использовал код из вопроса и все отработало... давайте еще подумаем

Comment: @АртемСавельев попробуйте еще раз, я добавил строчку в ответ

Comment: Результат тот же...
Может ли быть причиной капча на сайте?

Comment: @АртемСавельев запросто, это и похоже на непройденную авторизацию

Comment: @АртемСавельев рад помочь, и давайте удалим не относящиеся к делу комментарии отсюда =)